# combining two columns c1,c2 as c3 in a table

Tags: sql

```
c1  c2

10  30
20  40
```

C1, C2 are the two columns and i want the output as given below using sql query.

```
C3

10
20
30
40
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION`(implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT c1 AS c3 FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT c2       FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `UNION`, without `ALL` keyword the result of the query are only unique values. If you want to keep duplicate, use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT C1 as C3 FROM TABLENAME
UNION
SELECT C2 as C3 FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use a `UNION ALL` query to get the result:

```
select c1 as c3
from yourtable
union all
select c2 as c3
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcf17/1)

This type of query will *unpivot* the data from the multiple columns into multiple rows.

Depending on your database product that you are using, some have an `UNPIVOT` function that will do the data transformation for you.  For example, if you are using either SQL Server or Oracle, you could use:

```
select c3
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  c3 for col in (c1, c2)
) u
order by c3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcf17/3)

Answer (score 1):

This will preserve the ordering by table

```
SELECT 1 AS ordering, c1 AS c3
FROM mytable
UNION
SELECT 2 AS ordering, c2 AS c3
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ordering, c3
```

If you can't ignore the ordering column you can turn it into a subQuery

```
SELECT c3
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS ordering, c1 AS c3
    FROM mytable
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS ordering, c2 AS c3
    FROM mytable) a
ORDER BY ordering, c3
```